# How to make a virtual tty (tty0tty) look like a real serial port?

Tags: serial-port

I'm using [tty0tty](https://github.com/lcgamboa/tty0tty). The virtual serial ports appear as `/dev/tntX` where X is an integer between 0 and 7. Problem is, many apps require "real" serial ports, such as lightburn. So `/dev/tntX` devices don't show up in the list of selectable serial ports. Can this be remedied? Real serial ports show up as:

```
crw-rw----+ 1 root plugdev 188, 0 Mär 20 18:02 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw----+ 1 root plugdev 188, 1 Mär 20 18:02 /dev/ttyUSB1
...
```

whereas the virtual ones as:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 234, 0 Mär 20 12:46 /dev/tnt0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 234, 1 Mär 20 12:46 /dev/tnt1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 234, 2 Mär 20 12:46 /dev/tnt2
...
```

I suspect it has to do with the major device numbers being different. Is there some way to change/spoof this, perhaps using `ln` or `mknod`, possibly involving `/sys` or `/proc`?

Comment: I don't know *why* these ports don't show up in such programs (normally, they just allow one to enter the port name); aside from permission problems, they might simply need to be named correctly. Have you tried renaming them to something that looks more like `ttyS200` or so?

Comment: I tried pure symlinks, didn't work

Comment: that's why I asked whether renaming works.

Comment: that's why I mentioned pure symlinks. what are you talking about?

Comment: rename the device file! `mv oldname newname`